# Need to automate some simple actions of a drone

Tags: automation, drone

I am working on a student&enthusiast project that includes the participation of a few drones (copter-type). Right now, there is nothing complicated in their movements, just, for example 100 meters forward, 20 meters upward, rotate 90 degrees left, 50 meters forward etc.

I really need to automate it. But for now, I am dealing with ordinary cheap drones from al****express (and maybe I will be stuck with them forever, haha), so I have no ardupilot or px4 abilities to set up some specific flight missions.
Is there something that I still could do?

Comment: yes, you could design your project so that the automated actions are not required

Comment: Very little. What you could do, is to override the RC control by opening it and replace your joysticks with the commands coming from an Arduino board or similar. But in this case do not expect that the copter will fly straight, hover and so on. It will drift somewhere without a controller and probably, since you are going to fly it outside, it will be affected by wind, turbolences induced by the rotor etc.